# removing extra caracter from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello guys i am having issue using a token , since on my Api i get a token like this "A58986587" , so in my Ajax call the url look like that and it not working

```
http://localhost/api/summary?csrf="A58986587"
```

it need to be like this one : http://localhost/api/summary?csrf=A58986587 without double quote on the tokken

i am trying to find a work around unfortunately i wasn't able

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. Which would you like? Replace, splice, substring...

Comment: Hamid, you have to attach your attempted code, as well.  This is not a "do my work for me" website.

Comment: @Moose i taught my question is already clear i just need to remove the double quote from "A58986587"

Comment: Please, read [how to ask useful questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace(/\"/g, "")` to remove all `"`

```js
var url = 'http://localhost/api/summary?csrf="A58986587"';

url = url.replace(/\"/g, "");

console.log(url);
```